# How to change company when copy a record in Odoo 17?

Tags: odoo, odoo-17

I am trying to change company of a record when copying it from another record.
Here is what i tried
Method 1:

```
company_id = self.env['res.company'].sudo().search([('partner_id','=',self.name.id)])
new_rfq_id = rfq_id.sudo().copy().with_context(default_company_id=company_id.id)
```

Method 2:

```
company_id = self.env['res.company'].sudo().search([('partner_id','=',self.name.id)])
new_rfq_id = rfq_id.sudo().copy().with_context(force_company=company_id.id) # Here i used `force_company_id` argument too.
```

But no  luck. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What about `rfq_id.sudo().copy(default={"company_id": company_id.id})`? And what about just setting it afterwards per write?